# Affinity of a boolean function in adequate sets

Tags: logic

I follow a logic-course in university and have to determine whether a given boolean function f(x1, x2, ..., xn) is affine or not. Affinity of a boolean function is described in our course as:

> A boolean function f is affine if and only if f(x1, ..., xn) =
>   c0⊕c1x1⊕...⊕cnxn for all infills of binary values  for xi (i = 1, ...,
>   n) for a certain selection of c0, ..., cn ∈ {0, 1}

I don't really understand that definition. How can I apply it on formula's as x1 ⊕ x2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function $x_1 \oplus x_2$ is [affine](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_lookup?title=On%20the%20classification%20of%20Boolean%20functions%20by%20the%20general%20linear%20and%20affine%20groups&author=M.%20A.%20Harrison&publication_year=1964).

It can be written as $0 \oplus 1 x_1 \oplus 1 x_2$.

Because of $c_0 = 0$, the function is also called *linear* (see slide 40 [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~flac/pdf/BoolFct-6up.pdf)).

Comment: Ok, so when I understand it correctly and I convert x1 ⇒ x2 into algebraïc normal form, I become: 1 ⊕ x1 ⊕ x1x2. This means the implication is not affine because x2 depents on x1?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) BTW: the slideshow you included in your answer is very helpfull and clear :)